# Use of unassigned local variable when variable will always be assigned

Tags: c#

The code below (that will not be production code) will not compile because of an `Use of unassigned local variable 'dateTime'` Looking at it I can tell that the variable would never be unassigned at return time. Returning an out parameter in an Any clause is bad form, but why can't it compile?

```
 private static DateTime? ConvertStringToDateByFormat(string date) {
     DateTime dateTime;

     var acceptableDateFormats = new List<String>{
        "d/MM/yyyy",
        "d/M/yyyy",
        "d/MM/yy",
        "d/M/yy",
        "d-MM-yyyy",
        "d-M-yyyy",
        "d-MM-yy",
        "d-M-yy",
        "d.MM.yyyy",
        "d.M.yyyy",
        "d.MM.yy",
        "d.M.yy",
        "d-MMM-yyyy",
        "d-MMM-yy",
        "d MMM yyyy",
        "d MMM yy"
     };

     if (acceptableDateFormats.Any(format => DateTime.TryParseExact(date, format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))) {
        return dateTime;   
     }
     else {
        return null;
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the lambda passed to `Any` may not be executed - imagine that your acceptableDateFormats were an empty collection. The compiler could be smarter and see that it was defined before and it has some values, but like many other things which the compiler *could* do, it probably wasn't worth the effort of the developers of the compiler to implement such thing.

Comment: it's still an interesting one, because if the Any is not executed the method will return null. There is no code path to returning the dateTime that has not been initialised.

Comment: ya but the compiler would have to determine that in every case that Any returns true, the lambda was in fact executed, when all that is known is that a lambda was passed to a method, not how the method uses the lambda to arrive at its return value.

Answer (score 1):

Add to @carlosfigueira's answer: Additionally, The compiler will never know at compile-time whether your `date` variable can be parsed successfully and store it in your `dateTime` variable. Thus your `dateTime` variable may not be initialized when the program reaches your `return dateTime` statement.

Comment: Anytime you use an out paramater, it must be assigned to, so in a regular case when it's not inside a lambda, the compiler does know it will be initialized at that point. If date variable cannot be parsed into a DateTime, it gets set to DateTime.MinValue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the .Net compiler is checking the syntax of your code. And as you already pointed out, the dateTime object is not instantiate, which lead to an "invalid syntax".

Answer (score 0):

You could just assign it a value since you return `null` if it does not parse anyway

```
private static DateTime? ConvertStringToDateByFormat(string date)
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
     ...
```